# SQL query in Laravel Eloquent Query

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

How to produce query like below in laravel eloquent

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE column1=value1 
and (
        (column2=value2 or column3=value3) 
     or (column4=value4 or column5=value5)
)
```

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query can be expressed as

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column1=value1 
AND (
       column2=value2 
    or column3=value3 
    or column4=value4 
    or column5=value5
)
```

To use above in laravel you can follow [Parameter Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping) guide from docs

```
DB::table('table')
    ->where('column1', $value1)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($value2, $value3, $value4, $value5) {
        $query->where('column2', $value2)
          ->orWhere('column3', $value3)
          ->orWhere('column4', $value4)
          ->orWhere('column5', $value5)
          ;
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two nested `where()` statements:

```
DB::table('the_table')
    ->where('column', 'val')
    ->where(function ($q) {
        $q->where('column1', 'val1')
            ->orWhere('column2', 'val2');
    })
    ->where(function ($q) {
        $q->where('column3', 'val3')
            ->orWhere('column4', 'val4');
    })
    ->get()
```

If you need to pass a variable to the nested `where()`, you need to add a `use` on the inline function:

```
DB::table('the_table')
    ->where('column', $val)
    ->where(function ($q) use ($val1, $val2) {
        $q->where('column1', $val1)
            ->orWhere('column2', $val2);
    })
    ->where(function ($q) {
        $q->where('column3', 'val3')
            ->orWhere('column4', 'val4');
    })
    ->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
DB::table('the_table')
    ->where('column1', 'value1')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('column2', 'value2')
                ->orWhere('column3', 'value3');
        })->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->where('column4', 'value4')
            ->orWhere('column5', 'value5');
        });
    })->get();
```